# SMTP configuration for especific server

Tags: email, smtp, port, host

i was installing a software in a pet store where they have their own domain which is animalae.com.mx, and they gave me default values for the SMTP configuration

```
Host = smtpout.secureserver.net, 
Port = 465, 
SSL = Enabled,
```

I tried to send email with my SMTP class in C# with this configuration but it throw and exception error sending the mail. I search in a page where you can see the services of your server and tried to send again the email with the MX service host names which where smtp.secureserver.net and mailstore1.secureserver.net, and tried it with the same port and changing the SSL on and off, but still no success.

So my question is, do i need to setup other things besides de HOST, PORT AND SSL, i have tried to send email with a domain I own, using

```
Host = mail.mydomain.com
Port = 25
SSL = Disabled
```

And i can send emails correctly, so my question is,do i need to setup other things besides the PORT, HOST and SSL in the server mention before???

Comment: failed **HOW**? did you get an error message? email got thrown into spam? didn't send at all?

Comment: Let me change, that, its just and exception error sending the mail, i'm doing this with c#, using the SMTP class